# Cannot access properties of object

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, redux

I have ran into a very weird issue I cannot seem to fix. Basically I am taking a CSV file and parsing it into a JSON object to hold in my redux store. I have the parsing and everything working...or so it looks like it is working and everything compiled into a nice JSON object sitting in my store.

[image]

When I map over each item and log the object in my component it also seems to look correct and I have access to everything I need...so it looks.

[image]

The issue is when I try to use a property from those objects I get undefined no matter what. So for example `console.log(weatherData[i])` or `console.log(weatherData.keyname)` I can log the object as seen above. However when I try to log something like this `console.log(weatherData[i].capital)` or `console.log(weatherData.keyname.capital)` I get undefined.

I have no idea why this is happening and am very lost now, so if anyone has any ideas please let me know. I also have used `componentWillMount` and 'setTimeout' to ensure I have all the data before requesting it, but that doesn't fix anything for me either

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(weather.data.Kabul.country)`?

Comment: @randomir just tried and still got undefined

Comment: @BradyEdgar from the log in the first image you have an object with a `weather` key within, so in the `console.log` how do you store the object i.e it would be `myObj.weather`, etc. From you last comment `weatherData` is the variable right? so you will have `console.log(weatherData.weather)`.

Comment: @loretoparisi just figured it out, was double quotes wrapped around my keys

Answer (score 0):

Just found the issue, was very stupid but the keys on my object had double quotes around them which was causing issues when trying to target them! Couldn't tell since inspect and redux tool both also format with double quotes